# JSON access issue

Tags: jquery, json, api, getjson

I'm having a bit of an issue accessing the asterisk property. I'm using a handy chrome tool called "JSONView" to view and copy any paths/values I need so accessing any value is not the problem. The problem is that when I copy the path needed, it gives me this: query.pages.52397875.revisions[0].*

That obviously won't work since there's a number and an asterisk in there. What can I do to make this work?

[Picture of the API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NffPJ.png)

Comment: The same way you accessed `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work: `query.pages.52397875.revisions[0]["*"]`

Please try with this once.